# Why my mesh vertices are moved by the same offset and not by offset calculated by bezier curve

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, mesh, bezier

I have a tough one (I think) problem. I am prepearing a game with a part, which is a race. I want to make it similar to oldschool "Lotus" games. Player will see a car from behind, a a road should have turns from time to time. So my idea is to make a Mesh (road), which will have updated vertexes based on bezier curve. A game should check every vertex on the left edge of the mesh and check how much should it be moved to left or right. Same for right edge. Below is my code based on:

http://www.andengine.org/forums/post47301.html?hilit=%20mesh#p47301

Calculations of bezier curve are taken from QuadraticBezierCurveMoveModifier included in andEngine.

```
private Mesh createRoad(){

    //create triangles
    //
    //   E--F
    //   |\ |
    //   B--D
    //   |\ |
    //   A--C

    final int triangleCount = 10;
    int i = 0;
    final float pInitialX = 0;
    float pInintialY = 0;
    int vertexCount = Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE * triangleCount * 4;
    final float pColor = new Color(0f,0f,0f).getABGRPackedFloat();
    final float pBufferData[] = new float[vertexCount];

    for(int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < triangleCount; triangleIndex++){

        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = pInitialX;
        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = pInintialY;
        pBufferData[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.COLOR_INDEX] = pColor;

        pBufferData[((i+1) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = pInitialX;
        pBufferData[((i+1) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = pInintialY + 30;
        pBufferData[((i+1) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.COLOR_INDEX] = pColor;

        pBufferData[((i+2) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = pInitialX + 200;
        pBufferData[((i+2) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = pInintialY; 
        pBufferData[((i+2) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.COLOR_INDEX] = pColor;

        pBufferData[((i+3) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = pInitialX + 200;
        pBufferData[((i+3) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] = pInintialY + 30;    
        pBufferData[((i+3) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.COLOR_INDEX] = pColor;

        i = i + 4;
        pInintialY = pInintialY + 30;


    }

    final VertexBufferObjectManager vbom = engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
    final HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject pMeshVBOM = new HighPerformanceMeshVertexBufferObject(vbom, pBufferData, pBufferData.length, DrawType.STREAM, true, Mesh.VERTEXBUFFEROBJECTATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);

    road = new Mesh(300, 50, vertexCount, DrawMode.TRIANGLE_STRIP, pMeshVBOM){

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            drawByBezier();
            onUpdateVertices();
            this.mMeshVertexBufferObject.setDirtyOnHardware();

        };

        void drawByBezier(){
            float pBuff[] = pMeshVBOM.getBufferData();
            int i = 0;
            for (int triangleIndex = 0; triangleIndex < triangleCount; triangleIndex++) {

                pBuff[(i * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = getBezierX(i, 100, 0, 0);
                pBuff[((i+1) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = getBezierX(i+1, 0, 0, 0);
                pBuff[((i+2) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = getBezierX(i+2, 0, 0, 0) + 200;
                pBuff[((i+3) * Mesh.VERTEX_SIZE) + Mesh.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = getBezierX(i+3, 0, 0, 0) + 200;


                i = i + 4;



            }
        }
        float bezierX; 

        float getBezierX(int triangleIndex, float P1X, float PcX, float P2X){

            float t = triangleIndex / (triangleCount * 4);
            float u = 1 - t; 
            float tt = t * t; 
            float uu = u * u; 
            float ut2 = 2 * u * t; 


            return bezierX = (uu * P1X) + (ut2 * PcX) + (tt * P2X);
        }

    };


    return road;
}
```

Results are: 
When I put (i,0,0,0) in all getBezierX() (for all vertices:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/upuyjti66rtm44i/Screenshot_2015-05-07-15-02-17.png?dl=0

When I put (i, 100, 0, 0) for first one getBezierX() the result is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3231zxrwytot71/Screenshot_2015-05-07-15-03-41.png?dl=0

As you can see all first vertexes are moved by the same offset to the right (100). It does not matter what are other parameters, it is always moved by value of the first parameter. Why is that? Do I miss anything here?

**EDIT**

To clarify. I want to make this black block to be curved like a turn on the road. So its left and right edge should be curved. I wannt to use bezier curve to calculate x position of every vertice of every triangle of a mesh used. y positions should be same as they are. A mesh diagram is commented in the begining of the code. Co I would like to position points A, B , E along one curve , and C, D, F along another moved to the right.

Comment: I think this question should be rephrased entirely (re-reading it 3 times and I dont have the slightest clue what the question is) and placed to a different SE site, but upvoting it because of unconstructive downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a problem but I dont really understand why it was a problem. So in:

```
float getBezierX(int triangleIndex, float P1X, float PcX, float P2X){

        float t = triangleIndex / (triangleCount * 4);
        float u = 1 - t; 
        float tt = t * t; 
        float uu = u * u; 
        float ut2 = 2 * u * t; 


        return bezierX = (uu * P1X) + (ut2 * PcX) + (tt * P2X);
    }
```

I changed `float getBezierX(int triangleIndex, float P1X, float PcX, float P2X)` to `float getBezierX(float triangleIndex, float P1X, float PcX, float P2X)`and it works now. But why the int was a problem?

Comment: Because if triangleIndex is an integer, the result of integer divided by another integer will always be an integer, which is then assigned to "t". Since triangleIndex will probably always be smaller than (4*triangleCount), you will always end up with t=0.0.

Comment: So result of dividing int / int is always rounded to int?  Even if I divide 1/300 which gives me float?

Comment: Yes. So (1/300) and (299/300) will both give you 0 and 1/300.0 or 1.0/300 will give you what you really want.